# Bash equivalent of WebConsole.group()

Tags: bash, stdout

How would I duplicate this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group in bash?

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "outer level"
echo.group()
echo "first group"
echo.group()
echo "second group"
echo.endGroup();
echo "back to first group"
echo.endGroup();
echo "back to outer level"
```

Which would output the following:

```
outer level
    first group
        second group
    back to first group
back to outer level
```

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Bash is a shell; it takes commands and runs them and supports scripts.  It doesn't directly support logging as a facility, so it doesn't support logging groups.

Comment: I'm referring to the ability to group outputs to stdout, e.g. via echo

Comment: @SamHartman I've made the question clearer; please respond if it's still unclear or remove your downvote if it makes sense

Comment: Re: "existing script or solution" -- see category #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CharlesDuffy didn't realize that ty for pointing it out

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i modified the question to what I believe matches the criteria for on-topic questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is restricted to built-in, out-of-the-box functionality, it lends itself to a one-word answer:

**No.**

---

That said, you could write something easily enough:

```
# Here's your library: Only four lines
nestLevel=0
nestEcho()  { printf '%*s%s\n' "$(( nestLevel * 4 ))" "" "$*"; }
nestEnter() { (( nestLevel += 1 )); }
nestLeave() { (( nestLevel -= 1 )); }
```

...used thus:

```
nestEcho "outer level"
nestEnter
nestEcho "first group"
nestEnter
nestEcho "second group"
nestLeave
nestEcho "back to first group"
nestLeave
nestEcho "back to outer level"
```

Comment: I've changed the question to "existing script/solution"...idc if it's built-in to bash

Comment: I just gave you an implementation. It's four lines. Why would anyone bother to publish a library for something that takes four lines?

Comment: it could be one small part of a library with additional useful features